# Getting Bootstrap broker ip:9092 disconnected error from kafka spout

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka, apache-storm

Versions:

```
"org.apache.storm" % "storm-kafka-client" % "1.2.1"
"org.apache.storm" % "storm-core" % "1.2.1" % "compile"
Kafka: 0.10.1.0
```

I am getting following error/warnings, running in localCluster, from my kafka spout:

```
2018-06-28 00:00:34,930 AppInfoParser [INFO] Kafka version : 0.10.1.0
2018-06-28 00:00:34,930 AppInfoParser [INFO] Kafka commitId : 3402a74efb23d1d4
2018-06-28 00:00:34,931 WARN NetworkClient [Thread-40-KafkaSpout-executor[12 12]] Bootstrap broker ip1:9092 disconnected
2018-06-28 00:00:35,092 WARN NetworkClient [Thread-40-KafkaSpout-executor[12 12]] Bootstrap broker ip2:9092 disconnected
2018-06-28 00:00:35,251 WARN NetworkClient [Thread-40-KafkaSpout-executor[12 12]] Bootstrap broker ip3:9092 disconnected
2018-06-28 00:00:35,524 WARN NetworkClient [Thread-40-KafkaSpout-executor[12 12]] Bootstrap broker ip4:9092 disconnected
2018-06-28 00:00:35,629 WARN NetworkClient [Thread-40-KafkaSpout-executor[12 12]] Bootstrap broker ip5:9092 disconnected
2018-06-28 00:00:35,822 WARN NetworkClient [Thread-40-KafkaSpout-executor[12 12]] Bootstrap broker ip6:9092 disconnected
2018-06-28 00:00:35,927 WARN NetworkClient [Thread-40-KafkaSpout-executor[12 12]] Bootstrap broker ip7:9092 disconnected
```

Here is the code of Kafka Spout:

```
  private def getKafkaSpoutConfig(source: TopologyConfig) = {
    System.clearProperty("java.security.auth.login.config")  //tried this after getting error, no impact
    KafkaSpoutConfig.builder("ip1:9092,ip2:9092,ip3:9092,.....,ip10:9092", "topicName")
    .setProp(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "myConsumerGroup")
    .setProp(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer")
    .setOffsetCommitPeriodMs(100)        
    .setFirstPollOffsetStrategy(KafkaSpoutConfig.FirstPollOffsetStrategy.UNCOMMITTED_LATEST)
    .setMaxUncommittedOffsets(1000000)
    .build()
  }
  def getKafkaSpout(source: TopologyConfig) = new KafkaSpout(getKafkaSpoutConfig(source: TopologyConfig))
```

On debugging, I see following is the stack trace for this error:

```
maybeHandleDisconnection:568, NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater (org.apache.kafka.clients)
processDisconnection:396, NetworkClient (org.apache.kafka.clients)
handleDisconnections:464, NetworkClient (org.apache.kafka.clients)
poll:270, NetworkClient (org.apache.kafka.clients)
poll:232, ConsumerNetworkClient (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals)
poll:195, ConsumerNetworkClient (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals)
getTopicMetadata:253, Fetcher (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals)
partitionsFor:1318, KafkaConsumer (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer)
getFilteredTopicPartitions:57, NamedTopicFilter (org.apache.storm.kafka.spout)
refreshAssignment:54, ManualPartitionSubscription (org.apache.storm.kafka.spout)
subscribe:49, ManualPartitionSubscription (org.apache.storm.kafka.spout)
subscribeKafkaConsumer:657, KafkaSpout (org.apache.storm.kafka.spout)
activate:648, KafkaSpout (org.apache.storm.kafka.spout)
invoke:484, util$async_loop$fn__557 (org.apache.storm)
run:22, AFn (clojure.lang)
run:748, Thread (java.lang)
```

The same code was working for one Kafka setup, but for another setup of kafka of same version it started to give above error.

### Edit:

As par comments, I tried to connect to port 9092 of Kafka, Which I was able to do:

```
➜  git:(myBranch) ✗ telnet ipn 9092
Trying ipn...
Connected to my-kafka-app-396433.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Comment: Can you please show you can reach port 9092 of Kafka from your Storm machines?

Comment: @cricket_007 I am able to connect, see edited question. I am trying to run this storm via local mode from my Mac.

Comment: Can you enable TRACE logging, see if you get more information?

Comment: @cricket_007 I already have `conf.setDebug(true)` for Storm or do you mean anything else?

Comment: I don't know the Storm API, but I think you have a log4j config being applied at some level.

Comment: @cricket_007, Yes that is at DEBUG level.

Comment: Okay, and if you set that to TRACE, do any other, more useful errors appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening because of some version mismatch of kafka. The installed kafka version was `0.10.0.1` while the code was picking and executing with kafka-clients version: `0.10.1.0`.

It was happening as `storm-core` has a dependency of `kafka-clients` version: `0.10.1.0`, which can be overwritten, which I did but somehow it was not excluded properly in sbt. After some permutations it was working and final dependencies were looking like this:

```
Seq("org.apache.storm" % "storm-core" % "1.2.1" % "compile" excludeAll(
  ExclusionRule(organization = "org.apache.logging.log4j"),
  ExclusionRule(organization = "org.apache.kafka", artifact = "kafka-clients"),
  ExclusionRule(organization = "ring-cors"),
  ExclusionRule(organization = "org.slf4j", artifact = "*"),
  ExclusionRule(organization = "log4j", artifact = "*"),
  ExclusionRule(organization = "javax", artifact = "*"),
  ExclusionRule(organization = "javax.servlet", artifact="*")
)),
"org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "0.10.0.1" excludeAll(
  ExclusionRule(organization = "org.slf4j", name = "slf4j-log4j12"),
  ExclusionRule(organization = "log4j"),
  ExclusionRule(organization = "javax.servlet", artifact="*")
),
"org.apache.storm" % "storm-kafka-client" % "1.2.1" excludeAll(
  ExclusionRule(organization = "org.apache.kafka", artifact = "*"),
  ExclusionRule(organization = "org.apache.logging.log4j"),
  ExclusionRule(organization = "ring-cors"),
  ExclusionRule(organization = "org.apache.logging.log4j", artifact = "*"),
  ExclusionRule(organization = "org.slf4j", artifact = "*"),
  ExclusionRule(organization = "log4j", artifact = "*")
),
```